# How to use Typescript DOM lib on the server?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions, typescript-lib-dom

I am writing code for a Google cloud function. Here I want to use the URL standard including `URLSearchParams`. I found out that they are part of the TypeScript DOM lib, so I've added that to my tsconfig `lib` setting.

However, when I compile and deploy the cloud function I get a runtime error saying URLSearchParams is not defined.

What am I missing? I'm using TS 2.6

---

Here is my config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es6", "es7", "esnext", "dom"],

    "sourceMap": true /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */,
    "outDir": "build" /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */,
    "removeComments": true /* Do not emit comments to output. */,

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,

    /* Additional Checks */
    "noUnusedLocals": true /* Report errors on unused locals. */,
    "noUnusedParameters": true /* Report errors on unused parameters. */,
    "noImplicitReturns": true /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */,

    "plugins": [{ "name": "tslint-language-service" }],
    "skipLibCheck": false
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["build"]
}
```

And package.json dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "circular-json": "^0.4.0",
    "es6-promisify": "^5.0.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.5.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.7.3",
    "invariant": "^2.2.2",
    "joi": "12",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "node-fetch": "^2.0.0-alpha.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/circular-json": "^0.4.0",
    "@types/invariant": "^2.2.29",
    "@types/joi": "^13.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.85",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.52",
    "@types/node-fetch": "^1.6.7",
    "cpy-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "del-cli": "^1.1.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^3.15.1",
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.6.0",
    "tslint-language-service": "^0.9.6",
    "typescript": "2.6"
  }
```

Comment: Can you share your (abbreviated) package.config and tsconfig.json so we can attempt to reproduce?

Comment: If a function exists during development time (it's in your .d.ts files or tsconfig file) but it fails at run time, that often means that your actual web site (html page) hasn't loaded a needed library or your browser doesn't support a function that you use.

Comment: @Kokodoko I am not using a browser. The question was how to use this API *on the server*

Comment: @Fenton I've added them

Comment: @Kokodoko To clarify, newer versions of Node already implement this API, but because of Google Cloud Functions using Node 6, I am trying to use the Typescript implementation.

Comment: Sorry yes, you're working on the server. But typescript only adds types, not actual code. So if a function doesn't exist on Google Cloud you simply can't use it regardless if your Typescript compiler says that you can.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to update your compiler options to include `dom`:

Before:

```
"lib": ["es6", "es7", "esnext"],
```

After:

```
"lib": ["es6", "es7", "esnext", "dom"],
```

This is the library with the `URLSearchParams` interface.

With just the above change, I can place the following in `src/sub/temp.ts`:

```
let x: URLSearchParams;
```

And I get the following type information on hover, plus autocompletion.

```
interface URLSearchParams
var URLSearchParams: {
    new (init?: string | URLSearchParams | undefined): URLSearchParams;
    prototype: URLSearchParams;
}
```

There are zero compiler warnings.

This is all based on TypeScript v2.6.1... you aren't using an older version are you (pre v2.2?).

Comment: Ah sorry the config I posted was from a different branch. As I wrote in the description of my question, I already added the lib to my config. I'll update the config

Comment: It works for me with that addition, I have added how I tested it. What version of TypeScript are you using?